# writing an sql join based on three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have the following three tables in oracle database named A,B and C.

- The fields in the A table is AID(pk),AName,BID(fk).
- The fields in the B table is BID(pk),BAge.
- The fields in the C table is CID(pk),CSalary,BID(fk).

Now I am writing the join condition on three tables as

```
select a.AName from A a,B b,C c
  where a.BID=b.BID and b.BID=c.BID.
```

Is my way of writing the join condition on those three tables are right.Please suggest me.

Comment: Your query looks valid for Oracle, what exactly do you mean by "Wong Results"?

Comment: means in my join condition, i write a.BID=b.BID and b.BID=c.BID , here i am writing the query based on BID on both expressions,such that did i violate any join condition.

Comment: That's not the results, that's the condition.  You said that the query was giving you wrong results.  The query that you've provided should give you a list of all records that feature in all three tables where the salary field is 1000.  Is this not what you want?

Comment: my doubt writing those join conditions are correct or not based on BID.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the last comment; if you are asking whether the conditions are correct then, based on your table structure, they appear to be.  Maybe you could put the results you expect, and those you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

Try **join**::

```
select 
a.AName 
from A a
inner join B b on a.BID=b.BID 
inner join C c on b.BID=c.BID 

where c.CSalary=1000;
```

Comment: The alias `a` for the table `a` does not really make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I was trying not to change much in the existing query :-)

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix the problem as, as far as I can see, it will return the same results he currently has.